# How to Create a user in oracle on database name

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I am new to `oracle`, i want to create a user named as `abc` in oracle database, but i do n't know how to do it, please help me. My database name is `tom`. I wrote the following

`create user abc identified by abc.` But how can i link this user to my database `tom`?

After the user creation, `I want to import a dmp file in that user`, how can i import on user `abc`?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Firstly, this is a Q&A format, one question at a time please. Secondly, you must have logged in to a database to be able to issue the `CREATE USER` command. If you didn't log in to your `tom` database, where have you logged into?

Comment: I assume, he is just confused by the MySQL terminology.

Comment: if you are at all serious about learning Oracle, why not start with Oracle's own documentation?  Start with http://www.oracle.com/pls/db111/homepage or try googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original statement is correct. You can create a new user (using an existing admin user) like this:

**create user user_name_u by identified by password_p;**

Importing procedure can be different based on what kind of client are you using. But you surely have an SQLPlus, so this have to be enough: 
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ